# Summarize columns as new columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe df_workingFile:

```
group  | value
 a     |   1
 a     |   3
 b     |   2
 b     |   2
```

I want to add two new columns - one for the min and max for each group

```
group  | value | max | min
 a     |   1   |  3  |  1
 a     |   3   |  3  |  1
 b     |   2   |  2  |  2
 b     |   2   |  2  |  2
```

Right now I'm looping through each row and taking the min/max of the group's subset of data, but that's really slow with large datasets. What's an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `df$max = ave(df$value, df$group, FUN = max); df$min = ave(df$value, df$group, FUN = min)`

Comment: @Henrik I think you are a bit harsh on closing question as duplicates. Not necessarily this one, but I ran to two other posts today that you marked them as dupes which I wasn't quite sure about them to be duplicates of those threads. Of course you are the gold-badger ;)

Comment: @Masoud Thank you for your feedback! Please feel free to [cast a reopen vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) if you wish. (I just checked the ten most recent questions which I have dupehammered - so far no reopen votes on them, which may indicate that SO peers agree with my choice to close, as well as my choice of duplicate target).

Comment: @Henrik Don't get me wrong. I wasn't saying they were wrong but harsh. Anyhow, you know that chance of reopening a question is really low and it's even lower when they have been dupehammered. All in all, it was my point of view and it can be right or wrong.

Answer (score 4):

With the `dplyr` package you can do the following:

```
df_workingFile %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(max = max(value), min = min(value)) %>% ungroup()

  # A tibble: 4 x 4
   group value   min   max
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      a     1     1     3
2      a     3     1     3
3      b     2     2     2
4      b     2     2     2
```